# java substring within filreader while

Tags: java, substring, filereader

Can't find any help on how to do this:
I can't use .substring in the Filreader's while, it throws an exception after reading the first line.

```
String line = "";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(f) );
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(in);
while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(lnr.getLineNumber() + " : " + line.substring(1, 7) +"!");
}
in.close();
lnr.close();
```

Comment: Please add a better explanation of what you're trying to implement. Why are you using substring? What's the desired program output?

Comment: I want to read the File line by Line and if the Substring is == "whatever" then specific actions will follow. But substring seems to stop the Filereader, thats the whole problem~

Comment: On top of what @Mauricio said, what exception is it throwing?

Comment: Oh well, String index out of range, the next line has less then 7 characters as it seems. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Glad that you have already found the answer to your problem, additionally I would like to suggest adding a range check when calling substring (at least in cases where a variable length of line is expected)

```
if (line.length() > 7) {
  System.out.println(lnr.getLineNumber() + " : " + line.substring(1, 7) +"!");
}
else {
  System.err.println("Unexpected line, minimum expected length=7 chars");
}
```